# Redirection handling after promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

I'm working the authentification part of a website, here is the method called when the user send the connexion form :

```
login() {
   this.$store.dispatch('RETRIEVE_TOKEN', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
    })
}
```

And the action :

```
RETRIEVE_TOKEN(context, credentials) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('someurl/auth', {
       email: credentials.username,
       password: credentials.password
          })

          .then(response => {
              const token = response.data.key

              localStorage.setItem('key', token)
              context.commit('retrieveToken', token)
              resolve(response)

              this.$router.push('/backoffice')
          })

          .catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
             reject(error)
          });

        })
    }
```

My issue is that the `this.$router.push('/backoffice')` is called even if the user send the wrong password and usermail. I don't understand why. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: What are the contents of the response object in that case?

Comment: why are you returning a Promise?

Comment: The promise wasn't rejected. You need to check the response for a 400 error and handle accordingly.

Comment: Just `console.log` the response and check what are you getting. Also, no need to return a Promise:  
`RETRIEVE_TOKEN(context, credentials) { return axios.post('/someurl/auth', ...`

Comment: Off-topic but axios returns a promise so you should avoid creating another promise as this is an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm kinda new to axios and promises, I'm trying to figure out how it works. I want it to redirect to /backoffice + give a token if the user credentials match, or display an error message if not. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @blickblick you're not doing it wrong but if the response of the Http request is 200  or successful it will go to the then() function so in your then function there is no logic that traps the incorrect password or username or if checking the token, the catch() function is only triggered when you have a runtime or syntax error or if the Http request return 500 or other Error Status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that server returns 200 with an empty key even if username and password are not valid. We can add a condition to check if token is available or not

```
RETRIEVE_TOKEN(context, credentials) {
  return axios.post('someurl/auth', {
     email: credentials.username,
     password: credentials.password
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data) // If it not works, please show what's logged here
    const token = response.data.key

    if (token) { // check if token is valid
      localStorage.setItem('key', token)
      context.commit('retrieveToken', token)
      this.$router.push('/backoffice')
    } else {
      console.log('Token is not available')
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed!

Comment: It seems that I can't access to the router in the Vuex Store, despite the fact that I specified `import router from './router/index.js'`in the Vuex Store. Any idea why?

Comment: How do you set up the router in main.js?

Comment: Nevermind I'm dumb, I used $router instead of router ! Thank you very much for your help it helped a lot!